# Error "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \ tikz @ children @ list." with library mindmap and hyperref packages

Tags: hyperref, mindmaps

I've been trying to put the following url in quotation marks: https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2. But I always get the following error: "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \ tikz @ children @ list." . I am generating the pdf file through the latexmk -pdflua -pvc file.tex command. Below is the file.tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \centering
    \tikzset{every node/.style={font=\fontsize{4mm}{4mm}\selectfont,text width=4cm,minimum size=3cm}}
 \node [concept, text=blue!50!black!10,align=center] at (0,0) 
    {\href{https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2}{Problem}} 
child [concept] 
{node [concept] {\href{https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2}{n}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that if I make the code as below, I do not get this error. That is if I use the url only in the node parent and not in the node child.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \centering
    \tikzset{every node/.style={font=\fontsize{4mm}{4mm}\selectfont,text width=4cm,minimum size=3cm}}
 \node [concept, text=blue!50!black!10,align=center] at (0,0) 
    {\href{https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2}{Problem}} 
child [concept] 
{node [concept] {\href{https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2}{n}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add ``\catcode`#=12`` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Hi @egreg, "\catcode`#=12" really worked, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` was the problem, I think, and replacing it by `\#` seems to solve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={font=\fontsize{4mm}{4mm}\selectfont,text width=4cm,minimum size=3cm}}
 \node [concept, text=blue!50!black!10,align=center] at (0,0) 
    {\href{https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/\#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2}{Problem}} 
child [concept] 
{node [concept] {\href{https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/\#/books/9788522112654/cfi/98!/4/4@0.00:18.2}{n}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @marmot, the use of "\" where you indicated also worked, grateful.